# how to select distinct values from rows and columns both together

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: This is my database table.]

This is my database table with some values.There are different topic names from topic1 to topic8.
And I want to access the distinct topic names from all these values.
What will be the sql query for it ?

Comment: Before you take another step, please see normalisation. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Comment: @Strawberry Okay I will.thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: But you haven't :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the answers:
SELECT command with UNION operator returns itself distinct values. So it's not needed the DISTINCT keyword.

SELECT with UNION ALL returns duplicate values too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union query:

```
select topic1 as topic from t union
select topic2 as topic from t union
select topic3 as topic from t union
select topic4 as topic from t union
select topic5 as topic from t union
select topic6 as topic from t union
select topic7 as topic from t union
select topic8 as topic from t;
```

If you don't want `NULL`, then include a `WHERE` clause:

```
select topic1 as topic from t where topic1 is not null union
select topic2 as topic from t where topic2 is not null union
select topic3 as topic from t where topic3 is not null union
select topic4 as topic from t where topic4 is not null union
select topic5 as topic from t where topic5 is not null union
select topic6 as topic from t where topic6 is not null union
select topic7 as topic from t where topic7 is not null union
select topic8 as topic from t where topic8 is not null;
```

Comment: Unchecked, your phenomenal reputation alone may afford the OP the impression that this answer (and therefore their data model) is in some way appropriate in the context of an RDBMS. It's not. This answer would rate as an embarrassment were I not well aware that it's merely an aberration in an otherwise impeccable record.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT topic1
FROM TABLE
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT topic2
FROM TABLE
SELECT DISTINCT topic3
FROM TABLE
```

Repeat for all the necessary columns